# Best method for dealing with Unix compressed files (.Z) in IDL?

Tags: unix, ftp, idl, compression

I'm working on some code in IDL that retrieves data files through FTP that are Unix compressed (.Z) files. I know IDL can work with .gz compressed files with the /compress keyword however it doesn't seem capable of playing nicely with the .Z compression.

What are my options for working with these files? The files I am downloading are coming from another institution so I have no control in the compression being used. Downloading and decompressing the files manually before running the code is an absolute last resort as it makes things a lot more difficult as I don't always know which files I need from the FTP site in advance so the code grabs the ones needed based on the parameters in real time.

I'm currently running on Windows 7 but once the code is finished it will be used on a Unix system as well (computer cluster).

Comment: I think I found a sufficient solution, I can use 'spawn' to decompress the files through a system command before opening them in IDL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SPAWN](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/SPAWN.html) as you note in your comment (assuming you can find an equivalent of the Unix `uncompress` command that runs on Windows), or for higher speed you can use an external C function with [CALL_EXTERNAL](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/callextfn.html) to do the decompression.  Just by coincidence, I posted an answer on stackexchange the other day with just such a C function to decompress .Z files [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60879/94).